# Symfony4 Assets handle after deployment

Tags: assets, symfony4, webpack-encore

I just tried to deploy my app on a server and I have some problems wiht the assets.

I uploaded my app on a subfolder `rapp` so I have this `/var/www/html/rapp`

First : I had to change my publicPath on webpackEncore to include `/rapp/public` to have `/rapp/public/build` while just `/build` worked in dev (with the `php bin/console server:run` command)
is there a way to keep the publicPath inside the public Folder ? why I have to specify the subfolder ?

Second, with the first change It seems I have good URL to get my assets `http://domain/rapp/public/build/main.css` but it return a 404 for all my assets file (js and css)
I followed the recommended VHost (changed for some tests)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName domain.tld
    #ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

edit : added .htaccess on my root app folder and public app folder
root app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and public app folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /rapp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is my webpack encore config

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/rapp/public/build')

    // will create public/build/main.js and public/build/main.css
    .addEntry('main', './assets/js/main.js')
    //Add entry if other js/css needed. first parameter is the generated filename.
    .addEntry('reader', './assets/js/reader.js')

    //file upload with dropzone
    .addEntry('dropzone', './assets/js/dropzone.js')

    //Admin chapter js
    .addEntry('admin-chapter', './assets/js/chapter.js')

    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader()

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning()

    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
        'jquery',
    ])

    .configureFilenames({
        images: '[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

(I launched the Encore build with dev option, not production)

the manifest.json is created, all the files with versioning are created, but as the file request is without versionning, it seems it's not found.

I just started with webpack with this project so i'm a complete noob, and I don't know much about apache/htaccess config, so maybe I miss something obvious...

If I'm unclear with something, let me know it's quite late here and I can't think properly anymore ^^"

edit : I changed my vhost config (on a conf file : `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/rapp.conf`) and htaccess on my app folders (root and public)
I still not working though.

Comment: what's your directory structure? You should not need to change the configs from your dev and prod environments. Webpack encore should handle things from the working directory. e.g.  `.addEntry('js/file', './assets/js/file.js')` which will be put into your `.setOutputPath('public/build/')` will result in `public/build/js/file.js` Your public path should be the document root in your vhost config `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/public` Otherwise your Symfony configs will be accessible by Apache. e.g. resulting url should be `http://domain/build/asset.ext`

Comment: Hi I have a problem on top of that now, on URL http://domain/rapp/, the symfony app try to get the /rapp route (that doesn't exists, it's just the subfolder I uploaded my app into.
My structure is : `/var/www/html/rapp/*symfonyapp*`
my public is in `/var/www/html/rapp/public`
I updated my question post to make appear my htaccess and apache config for the `/var/www/html/rapp/public` folder.
+ Encore docs says to include the subfolder on the setPublicPath : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#my-app-lives-under-a-subdirectory

Comment: That's only if you have it configured that way, which you do not. e.g. your website is `http://domain` at `/var/www/html/domain` and your Symfony app is in `/var/www/html/domain/symfony` Configure your `vhost`  as defined in https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html for the optimized confiugration and delete the `.htaccess` files. So the `/var/www/project/public` is equivalent to `/var/www/html/rapp/public` You will need to restart Apache as well as delete your `rapp/var/cache/prod` Symfony shouldn't know about `/rapp` unless you added it to your conifgs

Comment: So I have to delete the `/rapp` prefix on my encore config ?
With the vhost as in this pastebin : https://pastebin.com/Y9b1k9RZ I can access the app, but with the /public folder in the URL (the main reason  I used htaccess) and my assets are stil not found.
it search on url like : http://xx.xx.xx.xx/rapp/build/main.449323e1afd2cea1e68faa2395e5590c.css (don't search in the publicfolder)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Symfony Configuring a Web Server documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi). Your Apache virtual host file should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName domain.tld

    #this tells Apache to load http://domain.tld from the specified directory
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/rapp/public
    #this sets the access rules of the directory
    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        #for Apache 2.4 replace the Allow entries above with this line
        #Require all granted

        #this is what loads symfony at http://domain.tld/route
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    #this allows the use of bin/console assets:install --symlink
    #which is executed when you run composer.phar install
    #which should not be needed since you use webpack for asset management
    #<Directory /var/www/html/rapp>
    #     Options +FollowSymlinks
    #</Directory>

    #this prevents routing from being executed on `http://domain.ltd/bundles/file.ext`
    #resulting in a simple 404
    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    #this prevents routing from being executed on `http://domain.ltd/build/file.ext`
    #resulting in a simple 404
    <Directory /var/www/html/rapp/public/build>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    #SetEnv APP_ENV prod
    #SetEnv APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>
    #SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Your webpack config should look like

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    //...
;
```

Then delete your `.htaccess` files as they should not be needed.

---

**Process new configurations**

Afterward restart your Apache server to load the new vhost configuration.

Then delete your `/var/www/html/rapp/var/cache/prod` and/or `/var/www/html/rapp/var/cache/dev` directories.

Open a terminal on the server and navigate to `/var/www/html/rapp`.

Then run `php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`
This should also execute symfony `cache:clear` and `assets:intall`

Then run `yarn build` which will process your assets to the `/var/www/html/rapp/public/build` directory.

However I strongly suggest deploying the production built files from `public/build` as opposed to installing node.js and webpack on the production server. As suggested in the [Symfony Documentation on How do I deploy my Encore Assets?](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-deploy-my-encore-assets)

---

**End Result:**

- navigating to `http://domain.ltd` will load your application from `/var/www/html/rapp/public/index.php`
- routes will be generated as `http://domain.ltd/route`
- webpack will output the files using the working directory `/var/www/html/rapp` where your Symfony app lives
- absolute url assets will be loaded as `http://domain.ltd/build/asset.ext`

---

As for webpack versioning of your assets, ensure you update your production framework configuration to load the manifest.json file as follows:

```
#/var/www/html/rapp/config/packages/framework.yml

framework:
    #...

    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'

    #...
```

Comment: I think I didn't forgot a thing from what you talked about apache2, but going on the `http://domain.ltd` don't redirect to my app.
And for now, it's on a test/dev server, so I don't want to have my base url to redirect to the app, I'd like to have `http://domain.ltd/rapp/` for my app
For the deployment of the Encore assets, I quickly read that but yeah, good to have someone to confirm it. thanks.

Comment: @Etshy please update your question with your desired end result. Right now you asked for "`while just /build worked in dev (with the php bin/console server:run command) is there a way to keep the publicPath inside the public Folder ? why I have to specify the subfolder ?`" So I'm confused as to what you're actually wanting. If your app is in a subfolder, you have a bit to reconfigure in Symfony between local/remote dev and prod environments, as it is configured to work with itself as the project directory and `public` as the document root by default.

Comment: Yeah I'll rewrite the whole question post when I have time (or create a new one, it's better, maybe)